# SP - How to change ID in URL and Redirect with Button Event

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net, url, redirect

I want to redirect to ID from SPListItem:

```
SPList wayList = web.Lists["WayBIll"];
SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
myQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Text'>" + id + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
SPListItemCollection myItemCol = wayList.GetItems(myQuery);

string wayBillID = myItemCol[0]["ID"].ToString();
int firstID = int.Parse(wayBillID);
```

**This is my page URL:**

```
http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Lists/WayBill/LirexEditForm.aspx?List=a554a5ff%2Ddbd4%2D4a49%2D8647%2D694310c90930&ID=172&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsf%2Dspsdev02%2FTestSite%2FLists%2FWayBill%2FAllItems%2Easpx
```

How to change **ID=172** to **ID=firstID**

**Where I insert FirstID in this redirect method?**

```
 SPUtility.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated

Just try below code:

Just replace SPUtility line with below code:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) + "?ID=" + wayBillID;
                SPUtility.Redirect(url, SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This not working...

Comment: Which error it gives?

Comment: ID not change, my problem is where I delete SPListItem[n], redirect me to ULR with ID where not exist.. and I want to redirect to firstListItem ID

Comment: This is my case.

Comment: You can pass your desired id at the end in string url

Comment: Yes, but where I delete, not redirect me to first ID, maybe positon of redirect it is not the right place in my code?

Comment: If you delete that record, then how will you redirect on that record?

Comment: I have a 5 records, where i delete a last 5th record, i want redirect me to 1st

Comment: Your comment is my problem is this question :)

Comment: Okay... Then you have to pass that id using business logic in that url.

Comment: Yes, my query get first row ID, next delete last row and i want to set first row  ID in url i redirect, after delete..

Comment: Your code may be delete that item and then you are redirected on that item so error occurs. Comment the item delete code and try to run if it successfully redirects or not.

Comment: Seen my answer..

Comment: Id is the end of URL, i want replace ID=98 after source..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40004/discussion-between-dikesh-gandhi-and-goshuy).

Answer (score 1):

Please try below mentioned code by which you can change the querystring parameter value

**UPDATED**

```
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
qs.Set("ID", "Your desired value which you want to change");
SPUtility.Redirect(qs, SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
```

Please let me know if it works as i haven't tried it.

Comment: okay, I'll try.

Comment: WHere is qs in SPUtility redirect method ?

Comment: is that works for you?

Comment: moment, I'll try :)